# Add the css ::before in a loop through list elements

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

I have an unordered list that I want to emulate the following css but in javascript;

```
ul li:nth-child(6n+1) a:before { background: #81ecec; } 
ul li:nth-child(6n+2) a:before { background: #ff7675; } 
......
```

I'm trying the following script,

```
const listItems = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
    // Loop through the NodeList object.
    for (let i = 0; i <= listItems.length - 1; i++) {
      listItems[i].setAttribute('data-text', listItems[i].innerText);
      randomColour = setBg();
      listItems[i].innerHTML.before('background:#' + randomColour);
      listItems[i].color.innerHTML = "#" + randomColour;
    }
```

but I get an error that listItems[i].innerHTML.before is not a function.

Comment: The `before()` method has nothing to do with the `:before` pseudo-element. It inserts a real DOM element before another element, it doesn't set CSS.

Comment: the `before()` method doesn't even exist on innerHTML, it exists on an element

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for changing the CSS pseudo-elements, you can try something like the snippet below.

If you want to change the color of specific element:

```
const li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
----LOOP through all li-----
li[i].style.color = randomColor;
```

```js
const listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Loop through the NodeList object.
for (let i = 0; i <= listItems.length - 1; i++) {
  listItems[i].setAttribute('data-text', listItems[i].innerText);
  randomColour = "blue"
  listItems[i].style.setProperty("--pseudo-backgroundcolor", 'blue');
}
```

```css
li:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: var(--pseudo-backgroundcolor);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
```